# Will IMAP be deprecated along with EWS API basic authentication being deprecated?

Tags: imap, exchangewebservices

Based on https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/upcoming-changes-to-exchange-web-services-ews-api-for-office-365/ basic authentication for EWS will be deprecated.

There is nothing in the article that references IMAP though and I am wondering if it will be deprecated for office365 since it uses basic authentication.

Comment: IMAP offers basic auth, but doesn't require it. There are also other ways to authenticate. IIRC gmail has disabled basic auth by default, although account holders can enable it by selecting a scarily-worded option.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've heard about SMTP, basic authentication will never go away since it is part of the protocol itself. I would imagine IMAP4 is similar in that respect.

It is best to see what Microsoft itself does - when (and if) they will start supporting XOAUTH2 authentication in their own products (Exchange and Outlook), then you'd need to start worrying about the Basic authentication. So far, this has not happened.